# Razor CheckBoxFor on List<string>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't seem to figure out how to get a list of strings to render in my form as checkboxes. Tried a few things from various sites and questions/answers on here with no luck.

MODEL

```
    var model = new ProjectModel()
    {
        ProjectType = new List<string>()
        {
            "Brand Creation",
            "Web Design",
            "Graphic Design",
            "Custom Programming",
            "E-Commerce",
            "Other"
        },
    };
```

VIEW - I've tried the following ways.

```
                @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectType)
                {
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => true, item)
                    <br />
                }

                    @foreach (var item in Model.Budget)
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBox(item)
                        <br />
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use Enum to display checkboxes. I know it's not your answer but you may consider doing this.

You have to do these step >

1. Enum

   ```
   [Flags]
   public enum ProjectType
   {
       [Display(Name = "Brand Creation")]
       BrandCreation = 1,
       [Display(Name = "Web Design")]
       WebDesign = 2
   }
   ```
2. Create Html Extension method

   ```
    public static IHtmlString CheckboxListForEnum<T>(this HtmlHelper html, string name, T modelItems) where T : struct
       {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           var displayAttributeType = typeof(DisplayAttribute);

           foreach (T item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>())
           {
               FieldInfo field = item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString());

               DisplayAttribute attrs = (DisplayAttribute)field.
                             GetCustomAttributes(displayAttributeType, false).FirstOrDefault();

               TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
               long targetValue = Convert.ToInt64(item);
               long flagValue = Convert.ToInt64(modelItems);

               if ((targetValue & flagValue) == targetValue)
                   builder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

               builder.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
               builder.MergeAttribute("value", attrs.GetName());
               builder.MergeAttribute("name", name);
               builder.InnerHtml = attrs.GetName();

               sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
           }

           return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
       }
   ```
3. Finally in your View

   ```
   @Html.CheckboxListForEnum("ProjectType", @Model.ProjectType)
   ```
4. Get posted value

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
   {
      string[] AllStrings = form["ProjectType"].Split(',');

     foreach (string item in AllStrings)
     {
        int value = int.Parse(item);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Tried your method, but when I post back it's not populating the property with the selected options. I am using 2 properties (one for the types they can choose, set as the enum. and the other is set as an enum for the SelectedProjectTypes.

Comment: I have added code to get posted value. please check 4th step.