# Enum value to checkbox C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, enums, setvalue

I'm kinda new to MVC and I was having some doubts about how to set an enum value to a checkbox.

Here's my Enum class example:

```
public enum Area : int
{
    [EnumMember]
    [Description("AllAreas")]
    AllAreas = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    [Description("FirstArea")]
    FirstArea = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    [Description("SecondArea")]
    SecondArea = 2,

    [EnumMember]
    [Description("ThirdArea")]
    ThirdArea = 3
}
```

The model:

```
    [DataMember]
    public List<Area?> Area { get; set; }
```

HTML:

```
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <label>Areas: <span>*</span></label>
                        <input id="chkFirstArea" name="chkFirstArea" type="checkbox"/> First Area
                        <input id="chkSecondArea" name="chkSecondArea" type="checkbox"/> Second Area
                        <input id="chkThirdArea" name="chkThirdArea" type="checkbox"/> Third Area
                    </div>
```

I know this is a silly question, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out how to make this work. If anyone could help, I would apreciate it :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but check this out it may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946387/razor-checkboxfor-on-liststring

Comment: Enum.GetValues(typeof(Area)); ?

Comment: This does not make sense. What is it your actually wanting to do. If you want to select one `enum` value, use a radio button list or a dropdownlist. If you wanting to select multiple values, then use the `[Flags]` attribute on the enum - `[Flags] public enum Area { None = 0, FirstArea = 1, SecondArea = 2, ThirdArea = 4, AllAreas = 7 }`

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes and Enums are not quite good to work together. In general, Radio groups are better with Enums, while Checkboxes work better with booleans.

If I were in your place, I would replace the list of areas by three booleans:

```
public bool FirstArea { get; set; }
public bool SecondArea { get; set; }
public bool ThirdArea { get; set; }
```

And bind the checkboxes by its simple way:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FirstArea)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SecondArea)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ThirdArea)
```

The fourth checkbox ('all') could be a detached checkbox that sets all the other three checkbox via JS.